# positive definite function on topological group

Tags: functional-analysis

If $f$ is positive definite continuous function on group $G$, if we cut the function by compact set or finite set, is it still positive definite?

Comment: what do you mean by "cut" exactly?

Comment: I mean $\tilde{f}(x)= f(x) if x in K compact, =0 if x outside compact set K.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Take $G=\mathbb{Z}$. The function $f(n)=(-1)^n$ is positive definite. Indeed, for all $a_n\in \mathbb{C}$

$$\sum_{n,m} f(n-m)a_n\overline{a_m} = \left|\sum_n (-1)^n a_n\right|^2$$

Now cut $n=0$ out. We get $\tilde{f}(n) = (-1)^n$ for $n\not = 0$ and $\tilde{f}(0)=0$ otherwise.

Now let $a_1 = 1, a_0=1$. Then,

$$\sum_{n,m\in\{0,1\}} f(n-m) a_n\overline{a_m} = f(0)a_0a_0 + f(1)a_1a_0 + f(-1)a_0a_1 + f(0)a_1a_1 =\\ =(-1)\cdot 1\cdot 1 + (-1)\cdot 1\cdot 1  = -2$$

Comment: When a finitely supported function is positive definite?

Comment: What do you mean? I can give an example... the function $f(n) = 1$ if $n=0$ and $0$ otherwise is positive definite, because $\sum_{n,m} f(n-m) a_n \overline{a_m} = \sum_n |a_n|^2>0.$

Comment: We do not have that good of a classification of positive functions. The only one I know is that $f(n) = \int_0^1 e^{2\pi i n t} d\mu(t)$ where $\mu$ is a positive measure on $[0,1]$. If you choose $\mu$ be the Lebesgue measure you get the function from my previous comment.

Comment: Like I mean is always finitely supported positive function positive definite in discrete group? If not always, under which condition they are?

Comment: It is not always true (e.g. take the function from my first remark but with a negative sign, or a minus of any positive definite). About the conditions, again, I may not be familiar with every condition existed, but in general it is hard to classify positive definite functions. Maybe @Ryszard Szwarc answer can help?

Answer (score 2):

It is well known  and easy to prove (proof at the end), that every  positive definite function $ \varphi$ on a topological group satisfies $$\varphi(g^{-1})=\overline{\varphi}(g),\quad |\varphi(g)| \le \varphi(e)\quad (*)$$
Therefore any nonzero  function vanishing at $e,$ the identity element, is not positive definite. It is worthwhile to consult the [Bochner theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner%27s_theorem) for further properties
of positive definite functions.

**Proof of $(*).$** Let $g_1=e$ and $g_2=g.$ The $2\times 2$ matrix $$\begin{pmatrix} \varphi(e) & \varphi(g^{-1})\\
\varphi(g) & \varphi(e)
\end{pmatrix} $$ should be positive definite, self-adjoint in particular. Therefore $\varphi(e)\ge 0$ and $\varphi(g^{-1})=\overline{\varphi}(g).$ The determinant is equal $\varphi(e)^2-|\varphi(g)|^2.$ It should be nonnegative. Therefore $|\varphi(g)|\le \varphi(e).$